# Snip string in half in javascript with for loop

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new to javaScript and I am trying to create a function to snip a name in half and then put the first name and last names in positions 0 and 1 in an array. can someone please tell me why the following doesn't work? I am familiar with regular java, but not javaScript which is a bit less intuitive for me.

```js
function cutName(name){
    var firstName = "";
    var lastName = "";
    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        if(name.charAt(i).equals(" ")){
           firstName = name.substring(0, i);
           lastName = name.substring(i+1, name.length+1);
           break;
           }
    }
    var nameArray = new Array();
    nameArray.push(firstName,lastName);
    return nameArray;
}

console.log(cutName("John Smith"));
```

EDIT: I understand there are other ways to do this with split for example, but I wanted to know how to do this with a for loop and substrings.

Comment: Why must it be a for loop?  If you `split(' ')` then you get an array of (at least) two tokens, if there is a space.

Comment: Even without split, you could `indexOf(' ')` to get the index of the first space.

Comment: Stuff you can do with strings out of the box: [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: I would recommend finding some tutorials/guides/etc. It'll be quicker and easier than muddling through unguided: canonical JS doesn't look much like Java (or act like it, in some important ways).

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks Dave. I was actually doing that but they all recommended using the split method or a couple of others.

Comment: There's a reason they recommend using split, :).  You're effective reinventing the wheel doing it with a for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in method `equals` for string, you should use [strict equality operator  `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)

```js
function cutName(name) {
  var firstName = "";
  var lastName = "";
  for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name.charAt(i) === " ") {
      firstName = name.substring(0, i);
      lastName = name.substring(i + 1, name.length + 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  var nameArray = new Array();
  nameArray.push(firstName, lastName);
  return nameArray;
}

console.log(cutName("John Smith"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const cutName = (name) => {
   if (name && name.indexOf(' ') > -1)
      return name.split(' ');
   }
   return null;
}

console.log(cutName("John Smith"));
```